# Jenkins workflow environment variables causing a failure

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

For this very simple workflow:

```
env.FOO = 42
node {
  sh "echo $FOO"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Running: End of Workflow
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: FOO for class: WorkflowScript
```

How do I access environment variables in workflow shell steps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had an issue where I needed to mix interpolation. Where part of the script is interpolated before, and part of the script is interpolated during.  The trick to to escape the variable(s) you want interpolated during the run with a backslash:

```
def FOO = 42

node {
  sh """
    BAR = "hello $FOO"
    echo \$BAR
  """
}
```

So $FOO is expanded before the script runs, and \$BAR is expanded during the script run.

Comment: that is a great tip!

Comment: This is because `$FOO` is both valid Groovy and valid shell. Either you want it expanded by Groovy using `"$FOO"` or you escape it to pass it to the shell using `"\$FOO"` or `'$FOO'`.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that with double quotes the string interpolation of Groovy kicks in and looks for a workflow scoped variable of FOO.

To fix use single quotes:

```
sh 'echo $FOO'
```

Note also you can use workflow variables in scripts with double quotes:

```
def FOO = 43

node {
  sh "echo $FOO"
}
```

This will expand the value of `$FOO` *before* the script is run.